# Why don't most sources classify "when", "where", and "why" as relative pronouns?

Tags: relative-pronouns

I am researching the use of relative pronouns and most websites, including the British Council, list only:

> who, whom, which, that, and whose

What about here?

> That's the house where I grew up.
>
> January is when we go on vacation.
>
> That broken window is why you are grounded.

Comment: Because _where, when,_ and _why_ have very limited use as relative pronouns. They are most common in headless relative clauses (or disjunctive embedded question complement clauses, depending), like the last two examples you give, which are pseudo-cleft constructions derived from _We go on vacation in January_ and _You are grounded because of the broken window_ in order to emphasize the last NPs, not to identify them the way an a restrictive relative clause does. It's not unusual for oblique _wh_-words to have limited usage; _how_ may not be used as a relative pronoun at all.

Comment: By the way, the proper way to "research relative pronouns" is not to search websites or the British Council or [other Authorities](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html), but rather to assemble a corpus of English sentences and see how the relative pronouns are used or not used in them.

Comment: @John Lawler Thanks John. What changes here "January is the month when we go on vacation." and here? "The broken window is the incident why you are grounded."

Comment: _When_ can only be used to start a relative clause modifying a time word, and _where_ a place word; _why_ can be used only if _reason_ is the antecedent. That's why these pronouns are used so comparatively often to mark headless clauses; there are so few antecedents they can have that they can be safely implied and therefore not expressed.

Comment: And I find _*The broken window is the incident why you are grounded_ ungrammatical; _reason_ is the only NP that would work for me. Zero is also acceptable instead of an NP antecedent, of course.

Comment: @John Lawler Kudos. I though reason and tried to avoid the collocation. Got two for one there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how *what* is also missing from that list.

> **What** she said is true = *that which* she said is true.

They apparently only include relative pronouns that usually refer to an explicit antecedent, as opposed to those that usually include their antecedents, as do *what* (always) and *where* (usually). It is just a matter of definition. In your examples, those words clearly function as relative pronouns.

Comment: Would you give me an example with two clauses?

Comment: _What_ is excluded from relative clause service, but still exists as a headless relative/embedded question marker. As does _how_ -- _This is how you do it_. In addition, clauses that would be headed by _where, when,_ and _how_ (if relative pronouns were allowed in the construction) also occur in relative infinitives: _the place (*where) to do it, the time (*when) to do it, the way (*how) to do it._

Comment: @JohnLawler: In German, they generally use the relative pronoun *wo* "where" to refer to an antecedent that is a time, like *am Tage wo...*, whereas Dutch prefers *dat*.

Comment: @SurvMach: An example of what, exactly?

Comment: @Cerberus Never mind. I misread your comment

Answer (score 0):

In comments, John Lawler wrote:

> Because *where, when,* and *why* have very limited use as relative pronouns. They are most common in headless relative clauses (or disjunctive embedded question complement clauses, depending), like the last two examples you give, which are pseudo-cleft constructions derived from *We go on vacation in January* and *You are grounded because of the broken window* in order to emphasize the last NPs, not to identify them the way an a restrictive relative clause does. It's not unusual for oblique *wh*-words to have limited usage; *how* may not be used as a relative pronoun at all.
>
> By the way, the proper way to "research relative pronouns" is not to search websites or the British Council or [other Authorities](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/academy.html), but rather to assemble a corpus of English sentences and see how the relative pronouns are used or not used in them.
>
> *When* can only be used to start a relative clause modifying a time word, and *where* a place word; *why* can be used only if *reason* is the antecedent. That's why these pronouns are used so comparatively often to mark headless clauses; there are so few antecedents they can have that they can be safely implied and therefore not expressed.